# How to divide a column with multiple values in different rows with same keys in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a quite new python user and I've imported a huge db that looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
   {'name': ["apple", "orange", "banana"],
    'attr': ["yeoolw, red, white", "red", "yellow, black"]
   }
)
df.head()
```

and I need to obtain something like:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(
    {'name': ["apple", "apple","apple","orange", "banana","banana"],
     'attr': ["yeoolw", "red", "white", "red", "yellow", "black"]
    }
)
df_new.head(6)
```

obviously there are a lot of different cases, the only rule is that in the end I have to obtain a db with only one 'attr' for each 'name' and repeat the 'name' where there are multiple 'attr' in order to do not louse the information,
can anybody suggest me the best and less time consuming solution to this problem?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pandas 0.25+, you can chain `explode` with a `str.split()`:

```
df.assign(attr=df['attr'].str.split(',\s*')).explode('attr')
```

Output:

```
     name    attr
0   apple  yeoolw
0   apple     red
0   apple   white
1  orange     red
2  banana  yellow
2  banana   black
```